# Splicing into array of objects using setState update helper and event targets only works with initial array index and fails with all others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, immutability, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to build an app that will setState based on form select inputs with an onChange handlers. My state is an array of objects, and my form select inputs being created by mapping through another array of objects in order to set various form attributes that I will use to determine where and what is spliced into the state's array.

For some reason, my code works with the first mapped form, but fails on all others. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { draft_teams } from '../utils/draftinputs';
import { getPlayers } from '../actions/playerActions';
import { saveDraftboard } from '../actions/draftActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { 
    Form,
    Col,
    Button,
    } from 'react-bootstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import update from 'immutability-helper';

class DraftForm extends Component {

state = {
        draftboard: [
            {
                1: {team:'', player: ''}
            },
            {
                2: {team:'', player: ''}
            },
            {
                3: {team:'', player: ''}
            },
            {
                4: {team:'', player: ''}
            }
       ]
}

onChange = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        const pickName = e.target.name
        const pickValue = e.target.value
        const pickObjectName = e.target.getAttribute('label')
        this.setState((prevState) => update(prevState, { draftboard: [{ [pickObjectName]: 
        {[pickName]: {$set: pickValue}}}]} ))            
     }

render() {

        const { players } = this.props.player;

        return (
            <div className='mt-5'>
                <h5 className='mb-3 text-center'>Set Draft Board</h5>
                <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    {draft_teams.map(( { pick, name, player }) => (
                        <Form.Row>
                        <Form.Group as={Col} sm={.5} controlId="formGridPosition">
                            <Form.Label>Pick #</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control   
                                defaultValue={pick}
                                className='mb-2'
                                size='sm'
                                name='pick'
                                label={pick}
                                as="select" >
                                <option>{pick}</option>
                                </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPosition">
                            <Form.Label>Team</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control   
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                defaultValue={name}
                                label={pick}
                                size='sm'
                                className='mb-2'
                                name='team'
                                as="select">
                               {draft_teams.map(({ name }) => (
                                   <option>{name}</option> 
                               ))}   
                            </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPosition">
                            <Form.Label>Player - Consensus Pick {pick} - {player}</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control   
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                size='sm'
                                defaultValue={player}
                                className='mb-2'
                                name='player'
                                label={pick}
                                as="select">
                                {players.map(({ name }) => (
                                        <option>{name}</option>          
                            ))}
                            </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    ))}

                    <Button 
                        className='mb-5'
                        variant="success"
                        type="submit"
                        block
                        >Save Draft Board
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

DraftForm.propTypes = {
    player: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    getPlayers: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    player: state.player
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPlayers })(DraftForm)
```

Weirdly, it works perfectly with the very first form, but fails with all others, and I get an error stating the event.targets are undefined. Anyone know why this is happening? Thank you!
[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Ppx.png)

EDIT: Included full class code as requested

Comment: Can you add the rest of class Component?, I need it to replicate it

Comment: Please also be sure to include `update` as that function appears to be returning your new state object.

Comment: @AdrianNaranjo Updated with all the code. My state is actually consists of 32 objects but figured just to include the first few to get the idea of my structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$merge` instead of `$set`.

`$set` replace object

`$merge` replace or add property but maintain object properties

But the problem is that you need to include position in array, maybe you will need that `draftboard` would be object instead of array:

I will give both solutions:

- Continue with this structure:

```js
// state structure
state = {
        draftboard: [
            {
                1: {team:'', player: ''}
            },
            {
                2: {team:'', player: ''}
            },
            {
                3: {team:'', player: ''}
            },
            {
                4: {team:'', player: ''}
            }
       ]
}

// Test it in componentDidMount and it works
componentDidMount() {
    // this will change position 0 in `draftboard` and key 1 inside the object
    this.setState(
      prevState =>
        update(prevState, {
          draftboard: {
            0: {
              1: {
                $merge: {
                  team: "hey"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }),
      () => {
        // this will change position 1 in `draftboard` and key 2 inside the object
        this.setState(prevState =>
          update(prevState, {
            draftboard: {
              1: {
                2: {
                  $merge: {
                    team: "how"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          })
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

- Change to object:

```js
// state structure
 state = {
    draftboard: {
      1: { team: "", player: "" },
      2: { team: "", player: "" },
      3: { team: "", player: "" }
    }
  };

// Test it in componentDidMount and it works
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      prevState =>
        update(prevState, {
          draftboard: {
            1: {
              $merge: {
                team: "team1"
              }
            }
          }
        }),
      () => {
        this.setState(prevState =>
          update(prevState, {
            draftboard: {
              1: {
                $merge: {
                  player: "team1"
                }
              }
            }
          })
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Now if you want to change number properties in the second example by strings, final structure

```js
// state structure
 state = {
    draftboard: {
      pick1: { team: "", player: "" },
      pick2: { team: "", player: "" },
      pick3: { team: "", player: "" }
    }
  };
// update structure

// We will change property player of key `pick1` in draftboard
this.setState(prevState =>
    update(prevState, {
        draftboard: {
            ['pick1']: {
             $merge: {
                player: "team1"
              }
            }
         }
     })
);
```

Comment: Amazing man, thank you. You first solution worked perfectly. Do you have any idea why $set only worked for the first form while not for the others? Just incase it comes up again. Thanks again!!